# Add data element to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I have a link. Like this:

```
<a href="#" title="Title from this link"></a>
```

I want remove this title and put the title text in a data attribute. As data-title. How can i make this with jquery. 
So remove the title element. And place the text of the title element. In a new title data element.

Thanks

Comment: Please show sample output

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// you'd probably wanna give an unique id to your anchor to more easily identify it
var anchor = $('a'); 
var title = anchor.attr('title');
anchor.removeAttr('title');
anchor.attr('data-title', title);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// set title data-title to value of title
$("a").attr("data-title", $("a").attr("title"))
// clear title
$("a").attr("title", "");
```

Also I would give your link a `class`, so this action doesn't run on every `a` on the entire page.

Answer (score 1):

User `attr` method to set the attribute of element. And `removeAttr` method to remove the attribute

```
 $("a").attr("data-title", $("a").attr("title"));
 $("a").attr("title", ""); 
 // or
 $("a").removeAttr("title");
```

*PS: Would suggest a unique id or a class for the anchor element*

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("a").attr("data-title", $("a").attr("title"));
$("a").removeAttr("title");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id="1" href="#" title="Title from this link 1"></a>
<a id="2" href="#" title="Title from this link 2"></a>

var t = $("a[title='Title from this link 1']").attr("title");
$("#2").attr("title", t);
```

Answer (score 0):

jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/NEBh4/

you can see the changes happen to the links in the result window by using firebug or any other dev tool

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//example code one
var tempLink = $('#link');//cash the jquery object for performance
tempLink.attr('data-title', tempLink.attr('title')).removeAttr('title');

/*In above example I used an id to capture the html element, which mean u can only do above step only for one element. If you want to apply above step for many links you can use the following code. In this case I'm using a class name for the link element*/

//example code two
$('.link').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('data-title', $(this).attr('title')).removeAttr('title');
});
```

});

HTML for the above example

```
<!-- for example code one -->
<a id="link" class="link" href="#" title="Title from this link"></a>

<!-- for example code two -->
<a class="link" href="#" title="Title from this link 1"></a>
<a class="link" href="#" title="Title from this link 2"></a>
<a class="link" href="#" title="Title from this link 3"></a>
```